# QImage memory leak

Tags: python, qt, opencv, pyqt, pyside

I've written a OpenCV application which basically grabs frames from a camera, does some image processing and displays the image in two edited variants. First, I've used `cv2.imshow()` to display the images, but while OpenCV (Build without Qt support) isn't able to provide modern GUI elements, I decided to use `PySide` for my GUI.

But since this I get this error after processing about 830-850 frames (no matter, what timer rate I use, or how much image processing I do):

```
QImage: out of memory, returning null image
```

for both of my image views in the GUI, and then in each loop this one:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The numpy array of typenum=2, ndims=3 can not be created) in NumpyAllocator::allocate, file ..\..\..\opencv-3.1.0\modules\python\src2\cv2.cpp, line 184
OpenCV Error: Insufficient memory (Failed to allocate 921600 bytes) in cv::OutOfMemoryError, file ..\..\..\opencv-3.1.0\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp, line 52
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/myfile.py", line 140, in process_frame
    img = QtGui.QImage(cv2.cvtColor(thresh_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR), self.width, self.height,
cv2.error: ..\..\..\opencv-3.1.0\modules\core\src\alloc.cpp:52: error: (-4) Failed to allocate 921600 bytes in function cv::OutOfMemoryError
```

Here's a part of my code (without image processing, but it also produces the error):

```
import cv2
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore
from threading import Thread


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, cam=0, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.camera = Camera(cam).start()
        self.title = "Cam %s" % cam
        self.counter = 0

        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.layout = QtGui.QBoxLayout(QtGui.QBoxLayout.LeftToRight)

        self.video_frame = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.thresh_frame = QtGui.QLabel()

        self.layout.addWidget(self.video_frame)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.thresh_frame)
        self.layout.addStretch()

        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        widget.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.setMinimumSize(640, 480)
        self._timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self._timer.timeout.connect(self.process_frame)
        self._timer.start(20)

    def process_frame(self):
        self.counter += 1
        print(self.counter)
        self.frame = self.camera.read()
        self.height, self.width = self.frame.shape[:2]

        thresh_img = cv2.threshold(cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY), 0, 255,
                                   cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
        thresh_img = cv2.erode(thresh_img, None, iterations=2)
        thresh_img = cv2.dilate(thresh_img, None, iterations=2)
        thresh_img = cv2.cvtColor(thresh_img, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

        img = QtGui.QImage(cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR), self.width, self.height,
                           QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        img = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(img)
        self.video_frame.setPixmap(img)

        img = QtGui.QImage(cv2.cvtColor(thresh_img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR), self.width, self.height,
                           QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        img = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(img)
        self.thresh_frame.setPixmap(img)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.camera.stop()
        event.accept()


class Camera:
    def __init__(self, src=0):
        self.stream = cv2.VideoCapture(src)
        (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()

        self.stopped = False

    def start(self):
        Thread(target=self.update, args=()).start()
        return self

    def update(self):
        while True:
            if self.stopped:
                return
            (self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()

    def read(self):
        return self.frame

    def stop(self):
        self.stopped = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow(0)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

In the Windows task manager I can see the RAM usage of my program:

[image]

At the point of crash, the app uses about 1.5 GB of RAM. I've tried using the `gc` module and `gc.collect()` after `del img`, no success.

What else can I do?

**EDIT:**

The threaded `Camera` class doesn't matter here, the error does also appear  without it.

Comment: Can you provide a complete standalone program which allows us to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Im not at home right now but I'll Post it soon! Any ideas how to delete the img instance??

Comment: @tfv I've updated my code right now. Would be nice if you may have a look on it...

Comment: Can you provide info on Python and OpenCV version? I have 3.1.0 and 
python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:40:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)], and your program crashes immediately with a Logitech camera.

Comment: I highly doubt `(self.grabbed, self.frame) = self.stream.read()` is an atomic operation. You should probably have a lock to prevent concurrent access between your threads. Unlikely to be the cause of the memory leak though. Have you tried PyQt instead of PySide as a test? PySide, in my experience, has quite a few memory leaks so it might not be your fault.

Comment: @tfv I have `Python 3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 19:28:18) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32` and OpenCV `3.1.0`

Comment: @three_pineapples I tried using the cam without a new thread, no success, the same error. Changing the GUI to PyQt5 did the job, thanks man! But while I don't even like the GPL PyQt is licensed under, might it be a good idea to open a bug tracker? Maybe someone can fix this in PySide...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a PySide specific bug, using PyQt will fix it. It's not even OpenCV related. It doesn't look like there will be a solution for using PySide right now...

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this bug is due to garbage collection issues when using python 3.x

A simple workaround using ctypes has been provided here https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-140 and https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4283#issuecomment-92773487

On the last link see the post "mfitzp commented on Apr 24, 2015". This worked for me!

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I alread found that about 3 months ago :D

Answer (score 1):

Look at my comment at PYSIDE-140: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-140

Avoiding mixing python objects with Qt objects. Try example below and avoid playing with refcounts fixing.

```
stream = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
grabbed, frame = stream.read()

height, width = frame.shape[:2]
data = Qt.QByteArray(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR).tostring())
qimg = Qt.QImage(data, width, height, Qt.QImage.Format_RGB888)

data.clear()
del data
```

Comment: This was looooong ago, but thanks you anyway. The refcounter method was just working fine for me anyhow.

Comment: Left it not only for you, but also for others looking for solution of the same/similar problem. Refcount workaround is not working with Qt5 with usage of QTextEdit. My solution above works for that situation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using `QStackedWidget` for switching between different views and `QTimer` to trigger the view switch (on certain conditions).

I was using `functools.partial` for passing arguments from one view to another, among which I did pass instances, such as `PIL.Image`, `QImage`, `ImageQt` and `QPixmap`.

That's where it went wrong. When such resources are passed from one view to another, they are not being cleaned well by the garbage collector.

What worked for me.

1. Declare all variables that you plan to pass from one view to another as class properties (in the constructor of your `QWidget`). Store all image resources (such as `PIL.Image`, `QImage`, `ImageQt` and `QPixmap`) in those variables/properties.
2. Don't pass any arguments (containing image resources) from one view to another.

---

Additionally if you're using PyQT with OpenCV, note that OpenCV 2.9 contains a bug, which causes memory leak. Make sure to upgrade to latest version (either latest 2.x or 3.x) before you spend hours on finding out where the memory leaks come from.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
Even though this is currently not relevant for me at all, I remember using a QStackedWidget, not 100% sure if it was in this application. As you can see in the traceback,I was using OpenCV 3.1.0 back then!